# is there a way to enable Colored Emojis in windows file explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, fonts, windows-11, file-organization, emoji

using emojis in windows file explorer (file and folder names for example) always show in black/white version of the emojis [image: black/white]

but i noticed that in windows 11 explorer tabs the colored emojis are actually supported.. [image: colored emojis]

i was wondering if there's a way to enable colored emojis everywhere else in file explorer

Comment: I'm sure there's no 'official' way to enable it. But there could be some registry tweaks to enable it... If I come across one, i'll be sure to leave the link below.

Comment: @tabby.sl my thoughts exactly. that'd be great, ty